# Автоматическое обнаружение Интернет-соединения

Tags: java, android, сеть

Есть код проверки Интернет-соединения:

```
if(Objects.requireNonNull(connectivityManager).getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            Snackbar.make(coordinatorMain, "Соединение установлено", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Snackbar.make(coordinatorMain, "Проверьте интернет-соединение", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
```

Приложение может проверить, есть или нет нет интернет-соединения, и вывести ответ. Но это будет один раз. Я же хочу, что бы оно динамически выводило информацию о соединении.

Т.е. приложение запускается при подключенном Интернете - выводится сообщение "Соединение установлено". Отключаем Интернет, выводим сообщение "Проверьте интернет-соединение".

Как это лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

Создаем BroadcastReceiver

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import classes.NetworkUtil;

public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

            boolean IsConnected = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
           // Toast in here, you can retrieve other value like String from NetworkUtil
           // but you need some change in NetworkUtil Class
        }
    }
```

Регистрируем в манифесте

```
<receiver
    android:name="receiver.NetworkChangeReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Класс NetworkUtil

```
package classes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class NetworkUtil {

    public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
    public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
    public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


    public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (null != activeNetwork) {
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                return TYPE_WIFI;

            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                return TYPE_MOBILE;
        } 
        return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
    }

    public static boolean getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
        int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
        boolean status = false ;
        if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
            status = true;
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            status = true; 
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            status = false;
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21226848/5330439)

[Как добавить Snackbars в BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31429609/5330439)